# Why does Laravel Eloquent default timestamps() not use DATETIME type?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, eloquent

I recently discovered, that the columns created_at and updated_at created by the `timestamps()` function use the TIMESTAMP type.
I know that there are many similarities, but the DATETIME type has a much higher range beyond the year 2038. So why does Laravel not bother to use the DATETIME type for these default columns?

Would there be a workaround to just create these columns manually while keeping the functionality that Laravel automatically updates the columns?

Comment: I am not sure in keeping laravel functionality but you can try these in migration: `$table->dateTime('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));` and `$table->dateTime('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))->onUpdate(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));`

Comment: more info in this laracast: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/migrations-timestamp-vs-datetime-vs-date-vs-timestamps

Comment: Could also probably do: `$table->dateTime('created_at')->useCurrent();` and `$table->dateTime('updated_at')->nullable()->useCurrentOnUpdate();`

Comment: Thanks for the link and the recommendation!

Comment: Laravel can use timestamp for things like created_at, updated_at because it knows that the value stored will be near real time and not before 1970 or after 2038

Comment: @Zohaib Well, but this basically puts you up until 2038 where you have to migrate anyway to dateTime columns